# one day - left arm, next day - right arm

Tags: bodybuilding, splits

Is it ok to train only one arm in this day and then next day the other arm.

I am asking because now I am training left and right biceps for example in the same day and feel rather tired in the end of this training.

I have already splitted exercises. For example if I train biceps today, then I don't train any other muscle in this day.

And I decided to split arms by days: one day left biceps, next day right biceps for example. Or maybe left biceps - in the morning, right - in the evening.

So my question is: is it wrong to train each arm (or leg) in different days. Can it cause asymmetry in muscles or any other bad results.

I am training at home without couch.

Comment: No, it's not okay for you to train an arm a day. Not only are you likely to cause imbalance, but the perception will likely allow you to do something stupid that can lead to injury. **And yes, you should be tired after the training of both arms if you worked hard enough.**

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD could you please give example or explain more widely what does it mean: "perception will likely allow you to do something stupid that can lead to injury"?

Comment: If someone doesn't understand the importance of training both arms together, it's possible the person might not understand the concept of keeping good forms while exercising or practising safety. One can see how that can lead to injury pretty quick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly possible, but IMO has very little practical value as working your arms separately limits you to a couple of exercises.  Plus, it *may* be harder to keep the load balanced so that your arms progress at the same pace.

Make sure you eat well and get enough sleep.  Fatigue builds up quickly if either of those is missing.